# C++11 MinGW 4.9.1 shared_ptr and const static class field result "Undefined reference"

Tags: c++, c++11, static, constants, mingw32

```
#include <memory>

class CItem
{
  private:
    int m_inner;
  public:
    static const int CAP = 1;
    CItem(int temp) : m_inner(temp) {}
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<CItem> TPItem;

int main()
{
  int tttt = CItem::CAP;
  CItem *temp = new CItem(CItem::CAP);
  TPItem temp2(temp);
  TPItem temp3 = std::make_shared<CItem>(tttt);
  TPItem temp4 = std::make_shared<CItem>(CItem::CAP); //On MinGW there error: "undefined reference to `CItem::CAP'"

  return 0;
}
```

- on Visual Studio 2012 it work normal.
- on minGW32 4.9.1 it say
  "undefined reference" for static const field of class when try create
  shared pointer with make_shared.
- other methods:
- copy this field to int and create shared with this int - **work**.
- create class object with new - **work**.

Where my fault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `CItem::CAP` is [odr-used](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) by `std::make_shared` (*emphasis mine*):

> **Informally**, an object is odr-used **if its address is taken, or a reference is bound to it**, and a function is odr-used if a function call to it is made or its address is taken. If an object or a function is odr-used, its definition must exist somewhere in the program; a violation of that is a link-time error.

Since [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) takes its arguments by reference, this counts as an odr-use.

which means you are required to provide an out of class definition as well:

```
const int CItem::CAP  ;
```

or avoid the odr-use such as in this case:

```
TPItem temp3 = std::make_shared<CItem>(tttt) ;
```

For reference the draft C++11 standard section `3.2` *[basic.def.odr]* says:

> An expression is potentially evaluated unless it is an unevaluated
>   operand (Clause 5) or a subexpression thereof. A variable whose name
>   appears as a potentially-evaluated expression **is odr-used unless**
>   it is an object that **satisfies the requirements for appearing in a
>   constant expression (5.19) and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion
>   (4.1) is immediately applied**.

`CItem::CAP` is a constant expression and in all the cases except this one:

```
TPItem temp4 = std::make_shared<CItem>(CItem::CAP);
```

the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied immediately.

Comment: Do you think you could work around the issue by wrapping CItem::CAP in std::make_shared with "int(CItem::CAP)", or providing a similar static getter?
make_shared would then forward a copy of the constant, therefore the CItem::CAP would remain "odr-unused".

Comment: @KABoissonneault sure, that looks fine, it is very similar to the `std::make_shared<CItem>(tttt);` case.

Comment: after some experement is best for me `std::make_shared<CItem>((int)CItem::CAP);`